# We say 'in the morning' but 'on weekdays' - why?

Tags: prepositions

> "I get up late in the morning"  --- In this sentence we have used 'in' before morning
>   "I get up early on weekdays" --- In this sentence we have used 'on' before weekdays.

Please let me know why we use 'on' for 2nd sentence and why we used 'in' for 1st sentence.

Comment: Because English.  (I feel like I should apologize for my native language.)

Answer (score 1):

In your first expression, the time you're specifying is "late in the morning." You're talking about the latter part of the morning hours.

- "I woke up early in the morning to see sunrise."
- "I took a nap late in the afternoon."
- "I started drinking early in the evening."

In the second expression, "early" stands alone. "On weekends" is describing the schedule.

- "I get up early on Tuesdays."
- "I sleep late on Wednesdays."
- "I go to work in the middle of the night on Fridays."

Answer (score 0):

The preposition on is used in connection with "day","on this day" parallel to German "an diesem Tag".
"on" is also used with days of the week, which contain the word day: on Monday, on Tuesday, and on weekdays.
"on" is also used when "day" is connected with "morning/night": on Monday morning, on Saturday night.

When "morning, afternoon," is used alone then the concept of period of time prevails and "in" is used: in the morning, in the afternoon.

"night" can be used with a lot of prepositions: at night, by night, during the night.